# Difference between OperationCanceledException and TaskCanceledException?

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, task

What is the difference between `OperationCanceledException` and `TaskCanceledException`? If I am using .NET 4.5 and using the `async`/`await` keywords, which one should I be looking to catch?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

[`OperationCanceledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.aspx) is simply the base class for [`TaskCanceledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception.aspx) - so if you catch the former, you'll still catch the latter.

Some operations on concurrent collections throw just `OperationCanceledException`, as there aren't any actual *tasks* involved (at least as far as the public API is concerned). See [`BlockingCollection.TryTake`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381899.aspx) for an example.

I would catch the `OperationCanceledException` just in case the task is cancelled due to an operation which itself just threw `OperationCanceledException` - you probably still want to treat that as "just cancellation".

Comment: I came up with a ForEachAsync mostly from Stephen Toub's blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/ .  Then if I throw an exception inside an `await enumerable.ForEachAsync( async () => { throw new ApplicationException( "Test" ); } );` somehow it is 'changed' to a TaskCanceledException.  Any idea how that might be?  This is problem for me as I want to catch a 'true' OperationCanceledException via catch ( OperationCanceledException ) but I don't want this TaskCanceledException (which should really be ApplicationException) caught.